# Get/filter documents based on field id

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have around 20 documents in the Firebase database which each have fields with an "id" with a value. How does one query the database to get/filter to return every document with a specific "id" and omit the rest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter data by id by below query:

```
this.firestore.collection("collectionName", res => res.where('userId', '==', yourId))
   .snapshotChanges().pipe(map(list => {
       return list.map(item => {
          return {id: ...item.payload.doc.id, ...item.payload.doc.data()}
       })
   })).subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data);
   });
```

Comment: This doesn't return an array of filtered documents by id

Comment: you have saved documents with id in them?

Comment: Yes, each field of a document has a 'userId' field

Comment: I have updated the answer in `yourId` you need to pass the desired `userId`